# identity theorem with a triangular region

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question: Let D be a triangular region in the complex plane with boundary $B$. Suppose that $f$ is analytic in $D$ and continuous on $D\cup B$. If $f$ is constant in one side of $B$ then show that $f$ is constant in $D$.

I want to use the identity theorem; Assume that $f(z)=c$, for $c\in \mathbb{C}$, on the side of $B$ that $f$ is constant, and let $g(z)=c$ for all z in $D\cup B$ then since we can find a sequence in the domain that $f$ and $g$ agree on that sequence,  $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z$ by the identity theorem. But since the domain $D\cup B$ is not open I am not sure about my idea above. Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you heard of the reflection principle?

Comment: So we can have an analytic continuation of $f$ to an open and connected set, which than the constant function on the same set has to be equal to $f$ for all z in the domain? Thanks.